# Timestamp format getting convert when Dataframe.toJSON is done in spark scala

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, timestamp

I have timestamp column in hive table that is read into Dataframe using the spark sql.
Once I have the Dataframe I convert the dataframe to JSON string using the toJSON function in Spark.

But the timestamp format is converted after applying toJSON to the dataframe

Code and output as follows.

```
scala> newDF.show(false)
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|current_ts                  |new_ ts                   |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2019-04-10 01:00:27.551022|2019-04-10 06:00:27.551022|
|2019-04-10 01:00:49.07757 |2019-04-10 06:00:49.07757 |


scala> newDF.toJSON.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{" current_ts ":"2019-04-10T01:00:27.551-05:00","new_ ts":"2019-04-10T06:00:27.551-05:00"}|
|{" current_ts ":"2019-04-10T01:00:49.077-05:00","new_ ts":"2019-04-10T06:00:49.077-05:00"}|
```

Above out is not accepted, we need to have the timestamp as its displayed in the Dataframe without casting it to String data type.

Output I need is as follows

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{" current_ts ":"2019-04-10T01:00:27.551022","new_ ts":"2019-04-10T06:00:27.551022"}|
|{" current_ts ":"2019-04-10T01:00:49.07757","new_ ts":"2019-04-10T06:00:49.07757"}|
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the expected output. Please see below:

> scala> val df = Seq(("2019-04-10 01:00:27.551022", "2019-04-10 06:00:27.551022"),("2019-04-10 01:00:49.07757", "2019-04-10
>   06:00:49.07757").toDF("current_ts","new_ts")

**Output**

```
scala> df.toJSON.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"current_ts":"2019-04-10 01:00:27.551022","new_ts":"2019-04-10 06:00:27.551022"}|
|{"current_ts":"2019-04-10 01:00:49.07757","new_ts":"2019-04-10 06:00:49.07757"}  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using Spark 2.4. can you please specify the version also.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are converting from datatype string to toJSON format while he mentioned in question he wants to convert from timestamp to toJSON.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but as @maheshgupta Mentioned I get that issue when the data type is as timestamp. What you have mentioned is string data type.